# Does the cvxpy replace the max function by MIP formulation under the hood?

Tags: gurobi, convex-optimization, constraint-programming, nonconvex-programming, cvxpy

Does the cvxpy replace the max function, which is convex, by MIP formulation under the hood when shows up in the constraints (for example, $\max(x,y)\le z$) or in the objective function?  In gurobipy, we need to introduce a new variable and new constraint: $L=\max(x,y)$ and $L\le z$

Then gurobipy converts it to MIP.

for example:

```
import gurobipy as gp
m=gp.Model()
x=m.addvar(vtype='C')       
y=m.addvar(vtype='C')       
z=m.addvar(vtype='C')       
L=m.addvar(vtype='C')       # new variable 
m.addConstr(L=gp.max_(x,y)) # new constraint
m.addaddConstr(L<=z)
```

`L=gp.max_(x,y)` is nonconvex, and gurobipy converts it to MIP convex under the hood.

$\max(x,y)\le z$
can b formulated in cvxpy as follows:

```
import cvxpy as cp
Cons=[cp.max(x,y)<=z]
```

Does cvxpy do something similar to gurobipy?

Thanks, @xd y!
My problem was the following: $$g+z\ge\max(x,y)+L$$ Does that mean it can be rewritten as $g+z\ge x+L$, $g+z\ge y+L$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Firstly you should use `cp.maximum` instead of `cp.max`. Secondly, it is converted to a convex programming problem (LP in this case, like $x \leq z, y \leq z$) since it follows [DCP](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html) rules, rather than introducing binary variables. To see that, you can try `Cons=[cp.maximum(x, y) >= z]` and solving the problem, you will see it fails to solve it.

Comment: My problem was like the following:
$g+z>=max(x,y) +L$
This can be rewritten as:
$g+z>=x +L$
$g+z>=y +L$
Thanks @xd y !

Answer (score 2):

Natively I am not sure since solvers that come do not have MIP capability
[Scroll down for list of solvers](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html)
And this [link to source code max](https://www.cvxpy.org/_modules/cvxpy/atoms/max.html) seems to suggest it uses max function.